# C# regular expression match

Tags: c#, regex

18.jun. 7 noči od 515,00 EUR

here I would like to get 515,00 with a regular expression.

```
Regex regularExpr = new Regex(@rule.RegularExpression,
                              RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline |
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline |
                              RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

tagValue.Value = "18.jun. 7 noči od 515,00&nbsp;EUR";
Match match = regularExpr.Match(tagValue.Value);

object value = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

regex is: `\d+((.\d+)+(,\d+)?)?`

but I always get an empty string (""). If I try this regex in Expresso I get an array of 3 values and the third is 515,00.

What is wrong with my C# code that I get an empty string?

Comment: I have 3 matches: `18` matches **\d+** ((.\d+)+(,\d+)?)? –> no groups; same goes for `7` –> no groups; `515,00` matches **\d+((.\d+)+** (,\d+)? **)?** –> 2 groups with the same contents (`,00`) –> there is no value for Groups[2].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex matches the `18` (since the decimal parts are optional), and `match.Groups[2]` refers to the second capturing parenthesis `(.\d+)` which should correctly read `(\.\d+)` and hasn't participated in the match, therefore the empty string is returned.

You need to correct your regex and iterate over the results:

```
StringCollection resultList = new StringCollection();
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?");
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

`resultList[2]` will then contain your match.

Comment: i try \d+(?:[.,]\d+)? but is the same Stil empty string

Comment: Did you use the entire code I posted, or just changed the regex?

Comment: just regex. Must i use StringCollection  too?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point. Your code is getting the second capturing group of the first match of the regex. What you want is the entire third match of the regex, and that's what you need the StringCollection for.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you escaped everything properly when you created the regular expression.

```
Regex re = new Regex("\d+((.\d+)+(,\d+)?)?")
```

is very different from

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+((.\d+)+(,\d+)?)?")
```

You probably want the second.

Comment: No: In the first the "\d"s are interpreted, where as in the second they're literal. The third, and equivalent to the second, example is: Regex("\\d+((.\\d+)+(,\\d+)?)?")

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the result you're getting in Expresso is equivalent to this:

```
string s = "18.jun. 7 noči od 515,00&nbsp;EUR";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+((.\d+)+(,\d+)?)?");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s))
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

In other words, it's not the contents of the second *capturing group* you're seeing, it's the third *match*.  This code shows it more clearly:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,10} {1,10} {2,10} {3,10}",
  @"Group 0", @"Group 1", @"Groups 2", @"Group 3");
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+((.\d+)+(,\d+)?)?");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s))
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0,10} {1,10} {2,10} {3,10}",
    m.Groups[0].Value, m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value);
}
```

output:

```
Group 0    Group 1    Group 2    Group 3
     18
      7
 515,00        ,00        ,00
```

---

On to the regex itself.  If you want to match only the price and not those other numbers, you need to be more specific.  For example, if you know the `,00` part will always be present, you can use this regex:

```
@"(?n)\b\d+(\.\d+)*(,\d+)\b"
```

`(?n)` is the inline form of the `ExplicitCapture` option, which turns those two capturing groups into non-capturing groups.  Of the RegexOptions you *did* specify, the only one that has any effect is `Compiled`, which speeds up matching of the regex slightly, at the expense of slowing down its construction and hogging memory.  `\b` is a word boundary.

It looks like you're applying all those modifiers blindly to every regex when you construct them, which is not a good idea.  If a particular regex needs a certain modifier, you should try to specify it in the regex itself with an inline modifier, like I did with `(?n)`.